# Cognos 11 - filter between query subjects

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

Given Table A with columns: ColA1, ColA2, ColA3

And a Table B with columns: ColB1

I want to restrict the data that can be returned from Table A based on data in Table B, like:

```
ColA1 not in ColB1
```

Ideally, some way incorporate SQL queries in the filter with select statements

Answer (score 0):

What you want is

```
SELECT a.ColA1
, a.ColA2
, a.ColA3

FROM TableA a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB b on b.ColB1 = a.ColA1

WHERE b.ColB1 IS NULL
```

So...
Query1 contains ColA1, ColA2, and ColA3 from TableA.
Query2 contains ColB1 from TableB.
Query3

- joins Query1 and Query2 on ColA1 1..1 = 0..1 ColB1
- Data Items:  ColA1, ColA2, ColA3
- Filter:  ColB1 IS NOT NULL

Comment: Would this be in the query subject, or in a standalone filter? In the query subjects, I have added some filters through a where clause, but they seem to not work. They work when running in SQL, as well as when running the Cognos 11 Generated SQL in Oracle, but I am guessing due to joins/links in Framework Manager the where clauses get broken somehow, and thus aren't working

Comment: I'm guessing you've never used Cognos before?  You don't put a WHERE clause in a data item expression.  In Cognos, you drag and drop.  What I described is creating 2 queries and joining them into a third -- and how to configure the join.  The SQL code was for reference in case you think better in SQL code than in Cognos GUI.

Answer (score 0):

not exists is probably what you are looking for

Try something like this

```
select * from TableA as T1  
where not exists                                                  
  (select * from TableB as T2         
    where t1.key1 = t2.key1 and T1.key2 = t2.key2)
```